# How to reorder the services startup - CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, system

I have added a new service to my CentOS box. It should be started after the mounting the file systems.

Would appreciate your assistance,
Liora

Comment: Well, at little bit more info (OS version, for example) and what you have done so far, along with your systemd/upstart/SystemV init script would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following line in `/etc/init.d/<your-service-script>` file.

```
chkconfig: - 00 99
```

This denotes it will start the service number as `00` (first) and while stopping it is `99` (almost last).

You can make it as `01` and it would be better.